# Unable to retrieve selected value in DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, drop-down-menu, webgrid

Trying to retrieve the selected value of my DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC. I'm using the following code:

**HTML**

```
 grid.Column("Other", header: "Other", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownList("OtherKey", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OtherKeysList, new { @class = "extra-class" })</text>)))
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Trying to retrieve the selected values of my DropDownList(in this case: otherkey3, otherkey2, otherkey1) with the code below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

       var dict = [];

       $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
           $('#tableID  > tbody  > tr >  td').each(function () {
               $('#OtherKey > option').each(function () {
                   console.log(($(this).val()));
               });
           });
       });

   </script>
```

However this does not work and I'm getting the following output:

[image]

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here.  First, you're getting the value of each `<option>` so it will always return all of the options, selected or otherwise.  Use `.val()` on the `<select>` itself to get the currently selected value:

```
console.log($('#OtherKey').val());
```

**However**, it also appears that you're re-using the `OtherKey` ID in your HTML.  Take a look at the actual HTML generated by your server-side code.  If IDs are not unique then the behavior of JavaScript code using those IDs is undefined.

Your elements do appear to be using a `class`, so you can use that instead.  (If it's not unique to those elements then you can assign them an additional class which is.)  Something like this:

```
$('.extra-class').each(function () {
    console.log(($(this).val()));
});
```

Note also that you don't need to loop through the table rows *and* through the `<select>` elements, just the latter is fine.  Unless you specifically need to identify your table rows for some other reason not shown here.